# how to show only last add button in the current cloned divs?

Tags: jquery, css

i have a code, which will clone the html element, i need to show "add" new button(which will clone the div) only for the bottom most copy. not for all cloned divs.

[codepen for this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwjgyJ)

```
     <div id="duplicater">
      <label>Number:</label>
     <input type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity"/>
    <button id="removebutton" class='remove'>Delete</button>
      <button id="add">add</button>
    </div>
     <div id="new_item_details" class ="new_item_details">
    </div>

   <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         var id = 0;
            jQuery(document).on('click', '#add', function(e) {
            var button = jQuery('#duplicater').clone();
            id++;
            button.removeAttr('id');
            button.insertBefore('.new_item_details');
            button.attr('id', 'new_' + id).attr('data-id', id);
            button.find('.remove').attr('data-id', id);
            e.preventDefault();

        });
         jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    var thisId = jQuery(this).data('id');
        jQuery('div[data-id="' + thisId + '"]').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    });


      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a CSS solution here can be much easier. (I wrapped your DIVs in a container).

```
#duplicater #removebutton {
  display: none;
}

div.container button.add {
  display: none;
}
#rows-container div:nth-last-child(2) button.add {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Notice that I used the `nth-last-child(2)` because you have another DIV after the actual rows with the `input` elements.

This is your updated codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwQzvN

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this, it works according to ur need

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var elem = '<div class="holder"><label>Number:</label><input type="number" class="quantity"/><button class="remove">Delete</button><button class="add">add</button></div>';
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(e) {
    $(".add").remove();
    id++;
    $(elem).insertBefore('.new_item_details');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    if ($(".holder").length > 1)
      $(this).closest('div').remove();
    if ($(".add").length == 0)
      $(".holder:last").append('<button class="add">add</button></div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="duplicater">
  <label>Number:</label>
  <input type="number" class="quantity" />
  <button class='remove'>Delete</button>
  <button class="add">add</button>
</div>
<div id="new_item_details" class="new_item_details">
</div>
```

Comment: sorry bharath, i dont want something works like mine, i want my code to be work.

Comment: in that case add

        $(".add").hide();
to start of the add button click  function and 

      button.find('.add').show();
to the end of the add button click  function.